# Nautilus auto-resize doesn't work properly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

Do you know how to configure Nautilus on Ubuntu's 18.04 such that when I  double click at filename column it will expands that column until largest filename length?

I think this was regular behavior on previous versions of Ubuntu? Does this also happen to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, currently in nautilus 3.26.3, double-clicking the right line of the column in the header "resets" the column width to some default width, which is not determined by the current displayed item. You can manually size the column width, and that size will be remembered. Yet, the logic behind how size is remembered and adapts to the window size is obscure to me.

Comment: Well, if I don't have any alternatives, the search has finished. :-) Tks for your attention and information.